# Nested Lambda with If conditions Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, multiple-conditions

I need to create a new column(FinalSL) for my daframe "copieddata1", with the follow condition:

[image]

1st step:

```
If ['defaultstore'] column = 1: then [FinalSL]= 4*['FCST: TOTAL'] column values
if no>  then check if ['SSS'] column is supporting the follow condition(2nd Step):
```

2nd step:

```
3*['FCST: TOTAL'] column values < ['SSS'] column values < 4*['FCST: TOTAL'] column values
```

So I have three possible outcomes:

```
1st' ['SSS'] < 3*['FCST: TOTAL'] then ['FinalSL']  = 3['FCST: TOTAL']
2nd' 3*['FCST: TOTAL'] < ['SSS'], but 4*['FCST: TOTAL'] < SSS tehn ['FinalSL']  = 3['FCST: TOTAL']
3rd' 3*['FCST: TOTAL'] < ['SSS'] < 4*['FCST: TOTAL'] then ['FinalSL'] = ['SSS']
```

Then, in summary I believe I have the follow conditions to apply in my code:

```
if SSS < 3*F then
   FinalSL = 3*F
else
   if 4*F < SSS then
       FinalSL = 3*F
else
    FinalSL = SSS
```

The I could create the idea for the 1step, but testing with a return the value 2 if the 1st condition from the first step is not true, but in fact this "return 2" should be replaced by the 2nd step conditions.

How can I be creating this ? I created the basic idea using lambda and the method apply:

```
copiedData1['FinalSL'] = np.where(copiedData1['defaultstore']==1,copiedData1['FCST: TOTAL']*4,2)
```

It worked, but now I need to do with the rights conditions from the 2nd step.

Any help would be very appreciated! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with nested `np.where()`'s. Roughly like this (pseudo-code-ish) answer:

```
df['FinalSL'] = np.where(SSS < 3*F, 3*F, np.where(4*F < SSS, 4*F, SSS)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pseudocode is quite unclear, so I went with your summary. You could translate this to a function:

```
def process_dataframe(row):
    if row['defaultstore']==1:
        if row['SSS'] < 3*row['FCST: TOTAL']:
            return 3*row['FCST: TOTAL']
        elif 4*row['FCST: TOTAL'] < row['SSS']:
            return 3*row['FCST: TOTAL']
        else:
            return row['SSS']
    else:
        return None
```

And then you could pass the dataframe through this function while assigning the new column:

```
df['FinalSL'] = df.apply(process_dataframe, axis=1) #axis=1 makes pandas pass the rows to the function in stead of columns
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/11380795/rj-adriaansen but how can I create a loop which will make run each row ? Because as you can see, I have at 20 rows in this dataset ? I mean how should I create the loops to store which row for the columns [defaultstore], [SSS], and ['FCST: TOTAL']  in this function ?

Comment: [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) takes care of that. No need to iterate over the rows in any other way.